# React Router sub-urls can't read Redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a route like this:

```
<Route path="/wishes/:wishID" exact component={WishDetail} />
```

*WishDetail* is a connected component.

Why can't I access directly http://www.example.com/wishes/43058304? I have a Firebase hosting set up as SPA so all requests should be redirected to /, therefore actions in my React app entry point should be dispatched.

In fact I can see redux-logger dispatching actions but I can't even read a boolean flag in the Redux state...

PS: I know about server side rendering, besides if you have some good source on how to setup SSR for Redux+Redux Thunk+Firebase it would be appreciated, but I need this to work without SSR for now

Comment: Have you tried without exact ? also are you using HashRouter or BrowserRouter ? Can you paste a bit more code including the versions you are using and the full Router config ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it work while in development point your index.html script tag to http://localhost:yourport/bundle.js or wherever you have configured output.path in your webpack config.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: This answers OP's question of wanting to a directly access a sub-url without using SSR. I don't see the issue with my answer?

Comment: Okay! But you can add this kind of suggestion or link or any reference on comment section.